# Why are there two different forms of the Characteristic Polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, characteristic-functions

Excuse me for my ignorance towards this topic. Unfortunately my professor waited to the last of day class to cover this important chapter.

He merely told us that the **Characteristic Polynomial** equation is:

(1)
$$p(\Lambda)=det(A-\Lambda_i I_n)$$

Yet, my textbook claims this **Characteristic Polynomial** equation to be:

(2)
$$p(\Lambda)=det(\Lambda_i I_n - A)$$

Where $n$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. In doing practice problems I've found the two the two equations to be equivalent. Unfortunately my textbook only provides the proof for the second equation. Therefore my question is: is one technically more "correct" or "formal" than the other? And why then are there two permutations of such a basic forumla--even if they are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, they both certainly return the same result when applied. Why then can we express the equation in two forms? Simply matter of preference? I cannot foresee where one could (or could not) hold true in even an extreme case

Comment: Ah that makes things more clear. I wish the author would have included a note about alternate forms. This book does indeed deserve the 2* Amazon rating.

Answer (score 2):

To repeat what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition) says about characteristic polynomials:

> We consider an $n×n$ matrix $A$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$, denoted by $p_A(t)$, is the polynomial defined by
>
> $${\displaystyle p_{A}(t)=\det \left(t{{I}}-A\right)}\tag{1}$$
>   where $I$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix.
>
> Some authors define the characteristic polynomial to be 
>   $$\det(A - t I)\tag{2}$$ That polynomial differs from the one defined here by a sign $(−1)^n$, so it makes no difference for properties like having as roots the eigenvalues of $A$; however the current definition always gives a *monic polynomial*, whereas the alternative definition always has constant term $\det(A)$.

---

I would say that one usually uses (1) for getting a monic polynomial. (2) is probably "more natural" for some people since when looking for an eigenvecotr, one solves $Av=\lambda v$ which is $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. To my knowledge, there is no anything deep among these two alternatives.

Comment: IMO, the "advantage" of the other form is that its value at $0$ is $\det A$. I like to think of it as of the determinate of $A$ "perturbed" by a multiple of identity.